# How can I setup iptables to allow communication for a specified port from a specified IP address only?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I have a database server (specifically Tokyo Tyrant) running on one machine and a web server running on a separate machine.

I need to setup iptables on both machines so that the web server can make queries on the database server. Currently, I get "connection refused" when I try this from the web server:

```
tcrmgr list ${ip_of_db_server}:${port}
```

Preferably, the db server should only accept traffic from the ip address of the web server.

I am new to iptables so this may be obvious, but I am struggling.

Any help much appreciated -thanks!

(Edit: 
NB. here's a list of my iptables rules:

```
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.179.51.126       tcp dpt:1948
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run something like this on the database server to allow inbound connections:

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -d ${ip_of_db_server} --dport ${port} -j ACCEPT
```

To see current rules in effect, run:

```
/sbin/iptables -L -v
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo for a basic intro.

Comment: Thanks -I had tried this already, but it still isn't working. It's good to know that I was on the right track though... I'm beginning to wonder if maybe this isn't an iptables issue after all (maybe it is the configuration of the database server?)

Comment: Have you tried plain old telnet ${host} ${port} to see if the server listens on that port? (Try first from within the server itself, if that works from a 3rd independent machine, then finally from the web server)

Comment: OK -telnet from the db server to itself using the required port seems to connect fine. But when I try the same thing from the machine hosting the web server it doesn't connect failing with : "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out"   -just had a thought -do I need to restart iptables or do the rules take effect immediately?

Comment: If you run /sbin/iptables directly, then the effect is immediate (if you edit a script, you should of course rerun the script).  Rule order matters.  ACCEPT should be before DROP.  Are you sure you do not have another (non-software) firewall between the servers?  Please add iptables -L -v output to the question if possible.

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/196702/how-long-does-it-take-for-an-iptables-rule-to-apply

Comment: Ah -I think this probably explains it, I had a DROP ALL rule above my new rule which I guess overrides it. Now my only problem is that when I try and delete the 'drop all' rule, it gives me an error: "iptables -D 5
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?)."

Comment: I realize my mistake now, I had originally used iptables -A instead of iptables -I. I should have read your answer more carefully. Thanks for your help!